# Unexpected output printf statement

Tags: c, macros, printf, ternary-operator

Why outputs of `i` and `j` in the following two `printf()`s are different?

```
#include <cstdio>
#define MAX(x,y) (x)>(y)?(x):(y)
int main()
{
    int i=10,j=5,k=0;
    k==MAX(i++,++j);
    printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,k);
    i=10,j=5,k=0;
    k=MAX(i++,++j);
    printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,k);
    return 0;
}
```

I think only `k` should differ, but it is showing different output for all, `i`, `j` and `k`, in `printf()` statement. What is the reason?

Output :

```
11 7 0
12 6 11
```

Comment: Did you mean sing `=` in line `k==MAX(i++,++j);`?

Comment: So what is your expected output for each print statement?

Comment: @ilent2, question edited to make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`k==MAX(i++,++j);` is translated to:

```
  k==(i++) > (++j) ? (i++) : (++j);
/* 2       1       3  : Precedance */
```

In your case `i = 10` and `j = 5`, so the comparision would be `10` v/s `6` which would be true or `1` with **side effect** `i` becomes `11` and `j` becomes `6`. (Recall that: Macros are not functions)

As `k = 0` and not equal to `1`, `k==(i++) > (++j)` would be `false` and `++j` would be executed. Causing `j` to be incremented to `7`.

In latter case, there is no modification to the value of variables.

**When can I expect same output in both case?**
Even if you change the macro with a function, your arguments have the side effects, which would cause the output `11 6` for `i j`, so you are changing the variables using `++` operator, don't expect both statements to have the same values.

Answer (score 1):

- Let's analyse the output from first `printf()`

  1. Assuming you meant `=` instead of `==` in your code,

     ```
     k==MAX(i++,++j);
     ```

     gets *translated* to

     ```
      k = (i++) > (++j) ? (i++): (++j)
     ```

     which gets evaluated changing all the values of `i`, `j` and `k`.
  2. Even if you meant `==`, as mentioned [in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30861535/2173917) by Mr. [Mohit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2659313/mohit-jain), you'll face similar issue with precedence.

  Have a look at [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for better understanding.
- Let's analyse the output from second `printf()`

In the second `printf()` statement, you're *re-setting* the values of `i`, `j`, `k` and not using the MACRO. So, those values will get printed. Simple.

So, **TL;DR,** before first `printf()`, the MACRO changes all the three values for `i`, `j`, `k`. So, your output for first and second `printf()` differs for all the three variable values.

---

FWIW, if you meant the MACRO to behave as a ternary conditional expression , you need to change your MACRO definition to

```
#define MAX(x,y) ( (x)>(y) ? (x) : (y) )
```

To avoid issues with operator precedence after MACRO expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You have side-effects.

```
MAX(i++,++j)
```

is expanded to

```
(i++)>(j++)?(i++):(j++)
```

And `i` is modified twice in the macro call.

Moreover, you have to add parens to your macro definition:

```
#define MAX(x,y) ((x)>(y)?(x):(y))
```

Comment: how? after `?` there __is__ a sequence point, isn't it? (Please correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: @SouravGhosh correct, I edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

i++ and ++j both increment i and j, so you change their values before printing.

Answer (score 0):

The macro is a red herring. OP did not ask about `k` but "Why output of i and j in following two printf are different?" The answer is because `i` and `j` have been modified between setting their values and printing, in the first case, but not in the second case.